# Create custom annotation same as @Before annotation in java

Tags: java, annotations

How to create before annotation. I want to execute a premethod before executing the actual method.
Ex:

```
public class MyClass1 {
    void preSubmit() {
    }

    @preMethod(name = 'preSubmit')
    public void submit() {
    }

    //No preSubmit execution here.
    private void otherMethod() {
    }

    private void otherMethod1() {
    }
}
```

- This preSubmit() should execute to only few methods in a class.
- There are many classes with same scenario.

With AspectJ, I can not specify all methods which requires preSubmit().

I want to create a annotation like same as @Before annotation in JUnit/AspectJ.

Comment: Why not just have several test classes and keep all methods that need the same init logic in the same test class?

Comment: This implementation is not for TestClasses to run with junit.  I have to setup few resources before a actual method call.

Comment: have you looked into JUnit rules?